# Does using CSS3 "background-size" speed up page rendering?

Tags: css, rendering

I would like to prevent unnecessary use of "background-size" in CSS3.
By the way, I am not resizing.

Comment: Does it speed it up compared to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `background-size` not speed up page rendering but it's helpful when you want a small image cover whole `background` at that time it's save the space of a big image .